# Matrix with input() shows 'IndexError: list index out of range' even if I have enough rows and columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix, input

Here's my code:

```
print("Please enter the positioning of each seat")

seat = [
    [input("Row 0: ")],
    [input("Row 1: ")],
    [input("Row 2: ")],
    [input("Row 3: ")]
]

print(seat[1][2])
```

I input random 4 rows and 4 columns of numbers:

```
Row 0: 3,6,1,1
Row 1: 7,4,8,2
Row 2: 6,7,4,1
Row 3: 4,8,9,0
```

Then the expected output is '8', right? But it gives me `IndexError: list index out of range`.
I KNOW that python list indexing starts at 0 which is why I put enough rows and columns. It works perfectly when I put the numbers directly into the code so I assume the problem is somehow related to the input() function but I cannot figure out the problem.

Comment: Did you try checking what `seat` contains overall (e.g. `print(seat)`)? Did you try simplifying the program by trying to make it work for a single row, to see if that works the way you expect? What if you try replacing the `input` calls with the strings that the user will input, *marked up as strings in the source code* - do you see the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[input("Row 0: ")]` would put one string called `"3,6,1,1"`, which causes the IndexError. You'll have to do `[int(x) for x in input("Row 0: ").split(",")]` in order to get integer values from comma separated input.

Your complete code should look like this:

```
print("Please enter the positioning of each seat")

seat = [
    [int(x) for x in input("Row 0: ").split(",")],
    [int(x) for x in input("Row 1: ").split(",")],
    [int(x) for x in input("Row 2: ").split(",")],
    [int(x) for x in input("Row 3: ").split(",")]
]

print(seat[1][2])
```